# Can I call a funcion when I stop to "resize" the window?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript resize event firing multiple times while dragging the resize handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667426/javascript-resize-event-firing-multiple-times-while-dragging-the-resize-handle)

Tried :

```
$(window).bind('load resize', function (e) {
    console.log("resized");
});
```

but it wrote "resized" for every small movement of the window. Can I call a function (In this example, that console.log()) only when I finish (I stop) to resize the window?

Thank you!

Comment: The resize event fires continuously while the dimensions of the window are changing; there's no event that would signal that resizing has finished.

Comment: This post in particular has your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/668185/54746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you simply define resize is finished if there is no new resize event within the next 100 ms. Like this:

```
var resizeEnd;
$(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(resizeEnd);
    resizeEnd = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("resized");
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Why your works and mine not? http://jsfiddle.net/FpXQq/

Comment: .setTimeout needs a function as argument. you need to change it to  timerResizer = setTimeout(function () {console.log("resized")}, 1000);

Comment: Besides you don't need that if (timerResizer !== false) check.. calling clearTimeout with undefined as argument is no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Resize would continuously fire while the window is being resized and it wouldn't fire when it is not being resized. So there isn't a way for you to recognize when a continuous resizing has stopped, so stick to logic that works upon firing of the resize event.