# Get window size continuously using jQuery

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-events

I do i get the windows size with jQuery?

```
winWidth = $(window).width();
        
$("#status").text(winWidth);
```

I have inserted this, but I get it only once. If I reduce the window, the value is the same. There is some way that this "event" can be always listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event in jQuery.It will update the size when ever you are changing the window size.In your case it is fixed.Which is caluculated while the page is loading.So you need to update that size when the window is resized.

```
var winWidth  = 0;
$(window).resize(function() {
  winWidth = $(window).width();
  $("#status").text(winWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jqueries `resize()` event.

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){
    winWidth = $(window).width();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you hook into the resize event and do a lot of processing on every change, you will freeze the browser, because the resize event triggers several hundreds per second on the desktop.

You need to do some debouncing on the function:

```
function updateOrientation() {
    // Detect whether device supports orientationchange event, otherwise fall back to the resize event
    // Genius solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2307936
    var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize", newAngle;

    if(supportsOrientationChange){
        newAngle = window.orientation;
        switch(newAngle){
            case 0:
            case 180: newOrientation = 'portrait'; break;
            case 90:
            case -90: newOrientation = 'landscape'; break;
        }
    } else {
        if(document.width < document.height){
            newOrientation = 'portrait'
        } else {
            newOrientation = 'landscape'
        }
    }

    // Do some processing here

    /*
     * Beautiful debouncing for resize event firing too much on the PC
    * by Pim Jager http://stackoverflow.com/a/668185/930987
    */
    resizeEvent = false;

    window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
        if(!resizeEvent) {
            clearTimeout(resizeEvent);
            resizeEvent = setTimeout(updateOrientation, 500)
        }
    })
   }
```

Comment: ???? How does this in any way, shape or form help him know the size of the window at any point in time?  It doesn't.  It's overkill and also plain irrelevant.

Comment: Well, 10 minutes later when he tests the simple resize(), will come back for this solution. Would have been simpler if, instead of "Do some processing here", I would have put "winWidth = $(window).width(); $("#status").text(winWidth);"? It's a generic solution to a problem, maybe will help some others.