# How to get the distance moved by the splitter?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, mvp

**Scenario:**

I am using a telerik:RadRotator and splitter.
I have 3 user controls on the page separated by the splitter. I have this telerik:RadRotator and vertical splitter is moved Horizontally on one control.

**Question**

Now, I want to resize the RadRotator as the splitter is moved. 
I have achieve that by this piece of code:

```
function resizing(sender, Args) {
    var rotator = $jQuery(".rrRelativeWrapper");
    var oldRotatorWidth = rotator[0].style.width;
    var width = parseInt(oldRotatorWidth.substr(0, (oldRotatorWidth.indexOf('px') + 1)));
    var newRotatorwidth = (width + (sender._width - width)) - 50;
    rotator[0].style.width = newRotatorwidth.toString() + "px";
}
```

But the problem is the "-50" that I have added to adjust the differences. This breaks the jquery if the splitter is resized at higher speed.

As I am not able to get the exact distance moved by the splitter when it is resized.

So, please can any one help me out how to get the exact difference in distance moved by the splitter?

**Note:** I want to write this Jquery on event **OnClientResizing** not on **OnClientResized**.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an event that is fired numerous times you may get a race condition and things may break. Use the event that fires when the resizing has finished. Otherwise, take a look here for an approach to fire the handler only once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/668185/812369.

Also, RadRotator does not support dimensions changes on the client, so things will not work as expected, I think. Take a look here for an approach that can work once you have the needed dimensions: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/rotator/setting-radrotator-s-size-in-percent.aspx.