# HtmlChart - Responsive Chart asp.net

Tags: asp.net, responsive, radhtmlchart

So i was trying telerik:RadHtmlChart to try make my chart more Responsive so that when the user resize the screen the chart resize too , but it is not working ..in the code they write  ""
but when i try to put it in my code its say that 'ClientEvents not supported ' any one know whey i checked the web.config and its seem fine 
help

```
<div class="demo-container">
        <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="BarChart" Height="300px" Width="100%">
            <ClientEvents OnLoad="chartLoad" />
            <PlotArea>
                <XAxis>
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="Item 1"></telerik:AxisItem>
                        <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="Item 2"></telerik:AxisItem>
                        <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="Item 3"></telerik:AxisItem>
                    </Items>
                </XAxis>
                <Series>
                    <telerik:BarSeries Name="Series 1">
                        <SeriesItems>
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="25"></telerik:CategorySeriesItem>
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="-12"></telerik:CategorySeriesItem>
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="39"></telerik:CategorySeriesItem>
                        </SeriesItems>
                    </telerik:BarSeries>
                    <telerik:BarSeries Name="Series 2">
                        <SeriesItems>
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="-15"></telerik:CategorySeriesItem>
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="38"></telerik:CategorySeriesItem>
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="-11"></telerik:CategorySeriesItem>
                        </SeriesItems>
                    </telerik:BarSeries>
                </Series>
            </PlotArea>
        </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following online resources show how to make RadHtmlChart responsive:

[Responsive Telerik RadHtmlChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876124/responsive-telerik-radhtmlchart)
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/functionality/responsive-chart/defaultcs.aspx
https://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/radhtmlchart-in-a-responsive-web-page

```
window.onresize = function () {
    $find("<%=RadHtmlChart1.ClientID%>").get_kendoWidget().resize();
}
```